# Java scanner, containing numbers

Tags: java, numbers, java.util.scanner

```
String[] invalidChars = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         try {
             String country = sc.next();
             String state = sc.next();
             String city = sc.next();

             if(country.contains(invalidChars) || state.contains(invalidChars) || city.contains(invalidChars)) {

             }
         }
         catch(Exception e){}
```

How would I tell an if statement to check if a string contains any number? I tried the array buy I get an error saying that "String[] cannot be converted to CharSequence"? Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a regex.

```
yourString.matches(".*\\d.*");  // returns true if the string contains a number
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward in your scenario would be to iterate through your invalid characters, one by one.

```
for (String invalidChar : invalidChars) {    
    if(country.contains(invalidChar ) || state.contains(invalidChar ) || city.contains(invalidChar )) {

    // do something
    break;
    }    
}
```

A cleaner way would be to use a regular expression checking for a match on [0-9].